# Should op amp reference terminal be connected to ground?

Tags: thermocouple, single-supply-op-amp

I would like to amplify the voltage from my thermocouple and had a couple of INA122s on hand. This is from the datasheet.

Should pin 5 be connected to GND? (pin 4)

[image]

Comment: be aware that the INA122 has an offset voltage of up to 250uV and 3uV/Deg. That may introduce significant error depending upon the type of thermocouple. A type K generates about 41uV/deg.

Comment: Thanks. I am using a Type K. I'm not 100% sure yet, but I just found that if I replace my 120 AC-> 12V DC power supply with a battery, the project appears to work. Maybe noise from the power supply?

Comment: An op amp doesn't have a reference terminal. This is an in-amp (instrumentation amplifier), a circuit made out of multiple op amps (usually 3, but sometimes, as here, 2 to keep cost down with some slight performance tradeoffs).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That an instrumentation amp (in-amp) not an op-amp. Pin 5, the output reference terminal (Ref), is show connected to ground. Pin 4 is shown connected to either ground or V-, depending on if you uses a single or dual supply. If you look further along in the [datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ina122.pdf) you will see several schematics where pin 5 is connected to pin 4. In some cases Ref can be connected to a voltage to offset the output. I would recommend giving the datasheet a good looking over.

Answer (score 2):

> *Question -- should pin 5 be connected to GND (ie, pin 4)?*

It's hardly ever connected to pin 4 (-Vcc). This is more usual: -

If you are using a split voltage supply then pin 5 (REF) is, in a lot of circuits, tied to GND. However, pin 5 offers an output offset adjustment and, it can be connected to a potentiometer or, even connected to the output of a DAC to facilitate this offset adjustment.

If using a single supply rail then pin 5 might usually be connected to a potential divider to offset it roughly half way between the rails. It can connect to pin 4 in some circumstances.

Comment: You will need to buffer your pot (and possibly your DAC output)! any impedance on the REF pin will significantly degrade your CMRR. See [this](https://i.imgur.com/gs0JNx6.png) (page 5-4) excerpt from AD's excellent [Designer's Guide to Instrumentation Amplifiers](https://www.analog.com/media/en/training-seminars/design-handbooks/designers-guide-instrument-amps-complete.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

You can tie it almost anywhere you like, and that can be a useful thing.

If G is the gain of the op amp, the output is G(V+ - V-) + Vref. So, if you tie the inputs together, the output will equal the reference voltage. Usually Vref is tied to ground, but it can be a useful way offset the output by larger amounts than the usual trims you can do with some op amps.

Comment: Thanks for these responses. It looked to me as if pin 5 could (should?) be grounded. I'm not getting amplification and was hoping that my grounding pin 5 was the problem. Clearly, no.

Comment: @couldabin - Are you "not getting amplification" in the sense that the output is zero, or in the sense that, with an AC signal in, the output is stuck at some DC value (like, +V -3, or -V + 3), In that case, especially if you are using high gain, one of your inputs is likely floating and needs to be properly connected.

Comment: the signal was showing around 2mV, regardless of the temp differential between the tip and the cold joint. I am pretty certain now that the problem is directly connected to EMI. I have been using a 120V AC adapter that outputs 12V DC as the power source. That goes though a 5V linear regulator that powers everthing. My DMM detects very little ripple -- if I set it to AC, it reads 5mV. BUT, I found that if I swapped the AC adapter for a battery, all the problems went away. Switch it back and the problem returns. Using a 12V battery for this won't be difficult.